# SAP Web-Service pass Binary Data to C#

Tags: c#, web-services, binary-data, sap-basis

I developed a little (working) Web-Service in SAP. It demands a Import Parameter and Responses an Export Parameter. The Web-Service is reached by an basicHttp Request from C#. As the next Step I now want to pass binary data (Type x255) from SAP as the Export Parameter. My Question is now how do I know which C# Datatype can Contain these Data.

Also: Is there a way to pass a whole (lokal-) Table as Export Parameter?

Comment: I would suggest you try and find out how you can get SAP to return something like JSON or XML (it's a fair bet that it *will support* XML I guess) - aside from this you **should not** return those stupid SAP tables as is even if the poor fool that has to use your service will somehow be able to make sense of this mess

Comment: Ok I will cross the Table return option of the list :). But does a SOAP Requests not always return its Data as XML?

Comment: yes (I think ... SOAP kindof died a cruel death so I try hard to not remember it) - but you did not mention SOAP at first - if it is SOAP than chances are high that you can just use the "WebReference" stuff in VS and don't have to think about any mapping at all - having said this most *Hipsters* prefer to use JSON ;) (and REST of course)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. All SAP data types can be used in web services (enterpirse services). 
But as @Carsten said, do not, expose SAP tables as is with it's ugly names. Help conusmer and provide meaningfull field names :)